# Migrating Spring Security 5 to Spring Security 6 HttpSecurity issue

Tags: java, spring-security

What should be the alternative of below code in Spring Security 6?

```
 http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .requestMatchers("/hub/**").access("hasPermission('SOME_LAYER', '')")
         .and()
     .exceptionHandling()
         .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandlerClass)
         .and() 
     .authorizeRequests()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
     .sessionManagement()
         .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER);
```

Comment: What part of your configuration is the problem?

Comment: What have you tried before asking?

Comment: It will be good if you can post the error message you are getting when you tried this in Spring security 6. You can check this link when you post a question- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Spring Security 6 the alternative of code as below

```
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            return  http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(c->c.requestMatchers("/hub/**").access(new WebExpressionAuthorizationManager("hasPermission('SOME_LAYER', '')")).anyRequest().permitAll())
                    .exceptionHandling(c->c.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandlerClass))
                    .sessionManagement(c->c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER))
                    .build();
        }
```